# JS: alternative to using filtering and mapping together?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return an array of the names who are not enabled.

```
let arr = [
   { enabled: false, name: 'Cal'},
   { enabled: true, name: 'John'},
   { enabled: false, name: 'Phil'},
   { enabled: true, name: 'Pierre'}
]
```

I am doing so with:

```
 arr.filter(x => x.enabled).map(y => y.name)
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Reuse `x` instead of  `y`. That's is the only improvement I can think of here. (Unless you're dealing with very large arrays, like millions of elements).

Comment: Within  a simple loop you can push to a new empty array and only iterate once instead of twice

Answer (score 1):

I ran some performance tests on some alternatives I've thought of. They assume the filter removes about 50% of the elements.
https://jsbench.me/xll0cli8cm/1

A simple for-of loop is by far the fastest, and in my opinion more readable than reduce is.

[image: Perf test results]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **flatMap** [here is the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
let arr = [
    { enabled: false, name: 'Cal'},
    { enabled: true, name: 'John'},
    { enabled: false, name: 'Phil'},
    { enabled: true, name: 'Pierre'}
]

//empty brackets return null
const mappedArr = arr.flatMap((item)=>{
    return item.enabled ? [item.name] : []
})
 console.log(mappedArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use reduce() function too.

```js
let arr = [
  {enabled:false,name:'Cal'},
  {enabled:true,name:'John'},
  {enabled:false,name:'Phil'},
  {enabled:true,name:'Pierre'}
];

var filteredArray = arr.reduce((a,b)=> {
  if (b.enabled) {
  a.push(b.name);
  }
  return a;
},[]);
console.log(filteredArray)
```

Comment: this is just console logging the name though , not returning a new array